# Suggest a way to find and replace values in xml file

Tags: linux, xml

I would like to find a parameter and update its corresponding value in a xml file.

Example:

Original file

```
"DefaultSecure" enable="true" in some.xml
```

Updated file

```
"DefaultSecure" enable="false" in some.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the structure of your XML file, it might be accomplished with regex search and replace, for which I prefer Notepad++.

You can find tutorials here: http://markantoniou.blogspot.com/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html